# Find the best decibel threshold to split an audio into segments with and without human voice in Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, audio-processing

I am trying to split audio into segments with and without human voice.  I've started to use the method  [split](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.effects.split.html) from [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html) and it does a really good job.
The only problem I am having is to define the best threshold for silence.

This method has an argument `top_db` (in decibels) that considers everything below it as silence. Currently, I am using a hardcoded value of 40 dB. For some audio, it works fine but for others not so much.

Is there a way to discover the best `top_db` threshold for each audio signal? Maybe considering the signal amplitude or average dB. Or normalize the audio wave amplitude before processing it, so a given `top_db` can perform well in most of the audio.

So far I have the following code:

```py
import librosa
import numpy as np

from pydub import AudioSegment


def to_normalized_array(audio_chunk, fs, librosa_fs):
   samples = audio_chunk.get_array_of_samples()
   arr = np.array(samples).astype(np.float32) / np.iinfo(np.int16).max
   return librosa.core.resample(arr, fs, librosa_fs)


audio_chunk = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio.wav")
audio_chunk = audio_chunk.set_sample_width(2).set_channels(1).set_frame_rate(16000)

fs = 16000
librosa_fs = 22050
top_db = 40

arr = to_normalized_array(audio_chunk, fs, librosa_fs)
edges = librosa.effects.split(arr, top_db=top_db) / librosa_fs
```

Thanks in advance,

Rhenan

Comment: Do you have some example audio that you can link to? Preferably one track that works ok, and another one that does not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Calculate energies the same way as librosa does (based on [_signal_to_frame_nonsilent and split functions](https://librosa.org/doc/main/_modules/librosa/effects.htm)

```
from librosa import feature
from librosa import core
mse = feature.rms(y=arr, frame_length=2048, hop_length=512) ** 2
mse_db = core.power_to_db(mse.squeeze(), ref=ref, top_db=None)
```

2. Instead of average db get percentile, e.g. 10%, assuming silence takes at least 15% of the audio. Add to it some small number to take into account variance in noise level

```
percentile_parameter = 0.1     # [%]
extra_db_parameter = 5         # [dB]
threshold = numpy.percentile(mse_db, percentile_parameter ) + extra_db_parameter
```

3. Provide this value as top_db

```
edges = librosa.effects.split(arr, top_db=threshold) / librosa_fs
```

Tweak those two parameters (`percentile_parameter` and `extra_db_parameter` to adjust to your case.